# Need to bundle a gem from a Fork, How can I do it for Rails 3.2?

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

I've been following the Bundler [Guides](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/git.html) in order to bundle a Gem from a Fork; The reason for doing this, is that the fork has commits to master that allow for compatibility with Ruby 1.9.x

So far I have this on my **Gemfile**: (following the syntax in the short guide)

```
gem 'yelp', github: "brenttheisen/yelp"
```

Unfortunately, the result of bundling like that is:

```
Could not find gem 'yelp (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/brenttheisen/yelp.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'yelp (>= 0) ruby'
```

Could you guys point me in the right direction to accomplish what I need?

PS. I've tried some answers from this site of course, but so far I've not been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I have just solved this, by following another item in the Bundler Guides:
More precisely it says:

> If there is no .gemspec at the root of a git repository, you must
>   specify a version that bundler should use when resolving dependencies

Therefore, I placed this line in my Gemfile:

> gem 'yelp', "1.0", git: "git://github.com/brenttheisen/yelp.git"

And it bundled correctly!